# How to use Keras `add_loss` exclusively

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am implementing a model that has a complicated loss term which requires the Keras `add_loss` function. I wish to implement my model as a `tf.keras.Model` (see [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/Model)). Unfortunately, it seems like Keras cannot deal with the case where `add_loss` is used, but `compile` does not get a loss function specification.

Here is a minimal example that "works" (doesn't do anything interesting, but no errors are raised):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np    

class Model(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Model, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)    
        self.layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, 
                       activation=tf.keras.activations.relu)

    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):    
        output = self.layer(inputs)
        return output


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.random.set_random_seed(1)
    m = Model()    
    x = np.array([[1., 2., 3.]])
    y = np.array([[0., 1., 0.5]])    
    m.compile(tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(), 
              loss=tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error)
    m.fit(x, y, epochs=100, verbose=0)
    print(m.predict(x))
    # [[0.         0.99999666 0.5000101 ]]
```

However, I don't need the "external" loss function, only one specified with `add_loss`, and this does not work. 
I had hoped that the following code does exactly the same thing as the one above:

```
# Same imports...

class Model(tf.keras.Model):

    # def __init__ ...

    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):    
        output = self.layer(inputs)
        error = tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error([0., 1., 0.5], output)
        self.add_loss(error)
        return output


if __name__ == '__main__':    
    tf.random.set_random_seed(1)
    m = Model()    
    x = np.array([[1., 2., 3.]])    
    m.compile(tf.keras.optimizers.SGD())
    m.fit(x, epochs=100, verbose=0)
    print(m.predict(x))
```

but it does not work. 
In particular, from `m.fit(x)` I get the error message

```
AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'total_loss'
```

One possible workaround is to add a trivial loss function

```
def no_loss(*args):
    return tf.keras.backend.constant(0.0)
```

but I had hoped for a more elegant solution.

I am using Tensorflow 1.13.1.